# $L^p(\Bbb R^n)$ spaces decomposition

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

Let us fix $1\le p<r<q$; fix an $l>0$ and take an $f\in L^r(\Bbb R^n)$; then we split the function
$$
f=\underbrace{f\chi_{\{|f|>l\}}}_{=:f_1}+\underbrace{f\chi_{\{|f|\le l\}}}_{=:f_2}
$$
and at this point my teacher wrote that
$$
f_1\in L^p(\Bbb R^n)\\
f_2\in L^q(\Bbb R^n)
$$

- Why is this true?
- Should I deduce from this that every $f\in L^r(\Bbb R^n)$ is the sum of of an element of $L^p(\Bbb R^n)$ and one of $L^q(\Bbb R^n)$?

Comment: the idea is that there are two ways for a function $g(x)$ not to be in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ : because it is too large on a finite subset, as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ on $[-1,1]$ which is not in $L^p$ if $p \ge 2$. and the other way is if $|g(x)|$ doesn't decrease fast enough when $|x| \to \infty$. separating those two parts (the infinite subset where $|f|$ is bounded, and the finite subset where $|f|$ is unbounded), you get on one side that $(L^p(\mathbb{R}) \cap L^\infty(\mathbb{R}))\subset L^q(\mathbb{R})$ whenever $q > p$, and on the other side $L^p([a;b]) \subset L^q([a;b])$ whenever $q < p$

Answer (score 2):

For $|f| \geq 1$, $|f|^{p_1} \geq |f|^{p_2}$ iff $p_1 \geq p_2$. (Multiplying by a number bigger than $1$ gives you a bigger number.) Thus $g=f \chi_{|f| \geq 1}$ inherits the integrability of $f$ as well as any *lower* integrability.

For $|f| \leq 1$, $|f|^{p_1} \geq |f|^{p_2}$ iff $p_1 \leq p_2$. (Multiplying by a number less than $1$ gives you a smaller number.) Thus $g=f \chi_{|f| \leq 1}$  inherits the integrability of $f$ as well as any *higher* integrability.

You can play around with constants to generalize this to arbitrary $l>0$, but the case $l=1$ is the most intuitive.

Your conclusion from this result is correct (and useful).